# Code works how I want it to, but with an "Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I want this to function how it does, to produce varying colors of dots when you click the "Make 'Em" button. However, in looking at the console, I noticed there's an Uncaught TypeError.

I think I have an idea as to why the error is occurring, that maybe it's because the getElementsByClass() function in the second for loop isn't seeing the classes generated by the first for loop because they're being generated after the fact, but if that's the case, then why is it working at all?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CIRCLES</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            background-color: black;
        }

        .circs {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #523674;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function makeCircles(){
            for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
                let circ = document.createElement('div');
                circ.className = "circs";
                document.body.appendChild(circ);
            }

            for (var x = 0; x >= 0 ; x++){  
                document.getElementsByClassName('circs')[x].style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200)+"px";
                document.getElementsByClassName('circs')[x].style.bottom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600)+"px";
                document.getElementsByClassName('circs')[x].style.backgroundColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999);
            }   
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="makeCircles()">Make 'Em</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Curious what the second for loop is about... `for (var x = 0; x >= 0 ; x++){ ` Greater than = to zero as your end condition?

Comment: `var x = 0; x >= 0 ; x++` .... welcome to infinity - so once `x` is greater or equal to `document.getElementsByClassName('circs').length` you'll get that error

Comment: My thinking was that it would apply the left and bottom styling to any additional divs made with the class "circs".

Comment: think about it .. x starts at 0, and keeps increasing while x >= 0 ... therefore, it keeps increasing forever (or until your error)

Comment: Yeah maybe I don't need the equal to part...

Comment: I would recommend `const circs = document.getElementsByClassName('circs')` BEFORE the loop... then use `for (var x = 0; x < circs.length ; x++)` and use `circs[x].` inside the loop - then relearn how for loops work

Comment: *maybe I don't need the equal to part* - but then `for (var x = 0; x > 0 ; x++){` will NEVER enter the loop ... because the condition is false immediately

Comment: That makes sense. I'm pretty new to for loops. Thanks for the input. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Because you should verify if the element exists before iterating.

Something like this:

```
    var circs = document.getElementsByClassName("circs");

    for (var x = 0; x < circs.length ; x++){  
       circs[x].style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200)+"px";
       circs[x].style.bottom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600)+"px";
       circs[x].style.backgroundColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're classes an creation of elements is fine. You just made a never ending loop with the line

`for (var x = 0; x >= 0 ; x++)`

I've switched this out to using a `forEach()` loop below. My preferred way of doing it.

```js
function makeCircles(){
            for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
                let circ = document.createElement('div');
                circ.className = "circs";
                document.body.appendChild(circ);
            }
            
            // convert the HTML collection to an Array
            var elements =[...document.getElementsByClassName('circs')]

            elements.forEach( (circle) => {
                circle.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1200)+"px";
                circle.style.bottom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600)+"px";
                circle.style.backgroundColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999);
            })   
        }
```

```css
body {
            background-color: black;
        }

        .circs {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #523674;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="makeCircles()">Make 'Em</button>
</body>
</html>
```